# Options for cheap, private month-long stay in Munich

Tags: germany, hotels, accommodation, munich, airbnb

I would like to travel to Munich for a month and am considering accommodation. I realize that [hostels are very cheap](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13139/can-i-live-in-munich-germany-for-a-month-with-500-eur), but I would be willing to pay more for a private room. Renting an apartment for a month is probably too short. Do hotels usually offer discounts for a month-long stay if I contact them? If so, around how much might it cost? Also, are services like Airbnb a good option?

Comment: I would suggest looking into "vacation rentals" or the like.

Comment: Also see the following question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14448/where-can-i-find-short-term-apartment-rental-offers-in-berlin

Comment: Finally, see here for information about munich: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23451/apartment-in-munich/23454#23454

Comment: "Are services like Airbnb a good option" - pretty subjective. Some love it, some hate it.  Suggest rephrasing :/

Comment: Why don't you get a private room at a hostel? Most of the offer the possibility and it is still cheap. You have to ask in advance if they will take you for a whole month though.

Comment: In the German cities where I've lived, there are Facebook groups for finding flats. Short term sublets pop up reasonably often there as well. That said, WG-gesucht is probably the best bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd give Airbnb a shot, though I never tried it personally.

In Germany such short-term apartment rentals are indeed nearly impossible. However you can maybe find something called WG - a roommate arrangement. Some of them may accept a short-term rent, maybe to fill for a sport which would be otherwise empty. A popular website to search for such places is http://www.wg-gesucht.de/.

Comment: Have to be careful with airbnb. Last time I stayed in Helsinki, it was a nightmare. In wg-gesucht, look for "ZwiMi/zwischenmiete".

Comment: specifically airbnb has a sublet page for that duration of stay: http://airbnb.com/sublets . there are several options for renting a private room for around 500 eur.

Answer (score 0):

If you are young, love company and can turn an eye to a thing or two, maybe you could give a shot to https://www.couchsurfing.com/ too. That maybe absolutely free anyway...

Comment: For a month? And more privacy than a hostel?

Comment: For a month... Yes there are people who are staying this long too. Privacy... Well depends on the host. But normally people are ok for you to have a private area